# Is there a way to cancel Chain Shot?

Tags: alpha-protocol

Without waiting for the bullet-time timer to tick all the way down or planting enough targets to fire all of my pistol's magazine (not clip), I can't end Chain Shot (CS) active skill once I've started it. Is there a way to cancel Chain Shot, in Alpha Protocol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send the mêlée command; press the button you use to perform a martial strike; click the key bound to initiate a close-quarters attack; try to punch/kick; do a karate chop.

Pro-tip: Canceling Chain Shot does not reset critical-shot meter, so you can use the bullet-time to line up a critical shot, cancel, take the shot, then reactivate Chain Shot immediately afterwards, effectively performing a Chain Shot without burning Chain Shot.